# How to update gridview widget with pjax in modal window in yii2

Tags: jquery, gridview, yii2

I'm using a modal with a `gridview (kartik)` on it.
When I want to refresh the `gridview` the modal closes when I use

```
$this->registerJs("
          $(document).on('click', '.applybtn', function(e){
                    $.pjax.reload({container:'#calendar_grid-1'});
          });
");
```

The line `$.pjax.reload({container:'#calendar_grid-1'});` will refresh the grid, but after the refresh it closes the modal.

Comment: Not sure it helps, but here is a similar question, but the guy solved without pjax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674432/how-to-update-widget-with-pjax-in-modal-window-in-yii2

Comment: I did see that question, but I think it's only possible to refresh the gridview with a pjax call.